# Python dictionary['key'] = .. results in a Tuple rather than a String in some cases

Tags: python

I need to copy fields from one dictionary to another. I'm seeing strange behavior where `dictionary['key'] = ...` sometimes gives me a `Tuple` rather than a `String` which I can't figure out.

Originally, I have a dictionary called `agreement` which has a String `alternate_address` field:

[image]

Then

```
formValues = {}
# ...
formValues['street'] = agreement.get('alternate_address', None),
```

gives me the following. Note that a similar field, `city`, also containing spaces, has no issues and remains a String, and I fetch it in exactly the same way.

[image]

Comment: `formValues['street'] = agreement.get('alternate_address', None),` - note the comma at the end. Your dictionary has a tuple because you put a tuple into it.

Comment: The trailing comma in `None),` makes the right-hand side a tuple.